# SQL 2008 - Combine multiple row values into one row with 'n' columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following table:

```
Row      Identifier    Property
1        stud1         R005
2        stud1         Z001
3        stud1         T001
4        stud2         R005
5        stud3         T004
6        stud4         null
7        stud2         T001
```

I want to be able to select this in the following format:

```
Col1              Col2     Col3    Col4   Col5 ...etc for 'N' rows...
Stud1             R005     Z001    T001   null
Stud2             R005     T001    null   null
Stud3             T004     null    null   null
Stud4             null     null    null   null
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of the other question, but if you look at this demo you will find a solution for both a static/dynamic solution --- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/883b9/3